# Eucalyptus/ubuntu-server-11.04 - instance is running but can't access it

Tags: ubuntu, eucalyptus, uec, ubuntu-enterprise-cloud, ubuntu-11.04

I've installed Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud on a server and I'm able to bring up an instance from a image and the instance shows that is running. I see the IPs allocated to that instance but for some reason I can't access it via SSH.

**euca-describe-groups** shows:

```
GROUP  admin default default group
PERMISSION admin default ALLOWS tcp 22 22 FROM CIDR 0.0.0.0/0
```

I'm on the same network as the instance so I'm sure is not an networking problem (like routers, switches etc.).

Any ides?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check would be

- Did the instance really start ? ssh
  to the NC, and try "virsh list", is
  it listed?
- A minimum UEC installation requires
  two nodes, with the NC node having VT
  support in the CPU. Can you login to the NC node and try "kvm-ok" ? what does that say
- Can you ssh into the instance from the CLC node ?

Comment: I have everything on the same machine. CLC, NC etc. I'll try your suggestions and I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed UEC on a single box where the node controller and the cluster controller on the same machine.

Make sure you create an SSH keypair in order to access the instance:

euca-add-keypair eucakey > ~/.ssh/eucakey

Then when you create an instance, create it with that key:

euca-run-instances -k eucakey emi-54E71716

Check to make sure that the instance is running:

euca-describe-instances

Finally, login to the instance:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/eucakey ubuntu@